# Google documents in google bigquery

Tags: google-drive-api, google-bigquery

Is there any easy way to read google documents in bigquery so that it can be called in Tableau? I am not a developer and would like to know if this is possible with or without SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Google BigQuery is a database for structured data. Unless your documents are .csv or .json that can be imported into BigQuery, you might need another type of solution.

Comment: Same applies to any sql or nosql system. You dont store docs there.